# Как экспортировать список установленный обновлений?

Tags: windows, обновления

Как экспортировать список установленный обновлений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Windows 2000/XP вроде как есть утилита для проверки установленных обновлений от microsoft - [qfecheck](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282784).  Ну и соответственно экспорт командой

```
qfecheck.exe >> c:\update_status.txt
```

Для Windows Vista/7, либо под Windows XP с установленным Powershell можно использовать

```
wmic qfe get >>c:\update_status.txt
```

Comment: Команда работает, но показывает похоже только обновления для Windows 7. А остальные обновления из списка "Обзор журнала обновлений" не показывает. Например, у меня там есть Обновление для Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553270), а в update_status.txt такого обновления не указано. Как получить и другие обновления?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (команда выдаст текстовый лог со списком установленных обновлений)

```
wmic qfe get
```

При желании можно задать другой формат (в виде html-файла, например).

Comment: Спасибо. По команде есть еще вопрос, см. ниже.